# Cannot Return CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> From Spring POST Request

Tags: java, spring, http, asynchronous, jax-rs

I am trying to return ResponseEntity from a post request after doing an asyncronous operation on spring boot server. This is simplified version of what i am doing:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/test/{id}")
@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> test(@PathParam("id") String id,
                                              @ApiParam String test) {

    CompletableFuture<String> completionSignal = new CompletableFuture<>();

    completionSignal.complete("qweqwe");

    return completionSignal.exceptionally(e -> {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle exception or return an error response
        return null;
    }).thenApply(completedStr-> {

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .header("test1", "sdfsdf")
                .header("test2", "gdfgdfg")
                .header("test3", String.join(",", "gdfgdfg", "gfggfgf"))
                .contentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .body(completedStr); // Assuming serverSdp is your response body

        return responseEntity;


    });



}
```

I get this as error:

```
2023-11-23 12:12:37,243 [http-nio2-0.0.0.0-5080-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor - MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/xml, type=class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity, genericType=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
```

Is there an alternative response data structure compatible with CompletableFuture, or is there a method to ensure that ResponseEntity works seamlessly with CompletableFuture?

My goal is to provide a well-structured response to the client, complete with headers. When I change ResponseEntity to a string and return a string, it functions as expected. I'm exploring potential methods to convert ResponseEntity to a string format that can be parsed by a JavaScript client following a fetch call. Specifically, I'm interested in retrieving headers from the response using response.headers.get("test1") in JavaScript.

Comment: `@Post` is from JAX-RS not from Spring. So JAX-RS is handling your web stuff and that doesn't support `CompletableFuture`. Your controller here seems to be in limbo as the `@RequestBody` is from Spring as well as `ResponseEntity`. So which is it that you want to use? JAX-RS or Spring MVC?

Comment: how should i reconstruct this if i am going to use JAX-RS

Comment: JAX-RS doesn't understand the spring classes. So don't use those use the JAX-RS ones, or ditch JAX-RS and use Spring MVC. If you replce the `@POST`, `@Consumes` and `@Path` with `@PostMapping(value=""/test/{id}", produces =  MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`. Replace `@PathParam` with `@PathVariable` it will use Spring MVC and it will work. AFAIK JAX-RS doesn't work with a completable future for async results but you would need to add the `AsyncResponse` as a method argument (annotated with `@Suspended`) and use that to generate the response to the client.